# Error al abrir archivo de excel con VB (error con DLL de office)

Tags: vb

> No se puede convertir el objeto COM del tipo 
>   'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel2000.ApplicationClass' al tipo de
>   interfaz 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel2000._Application'.
>   Ocurrió un
>   error de operación debido a que la llamada QueryInterface en el
>   componente COM para la interfaz con IID
>   '{000208D5-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}' generó el siguiente error:
>   Error al cargar la biblioteca de tipo/DLL. (Excepción de HRESULT:
>   0x80029C4A (TYPE_E_CANTLOADLIBRARY)).

¿Alguna idea?

¡Gracias!

Comment: En qué versión  de office se creó el archivo de excel? En cuál lo intentas abrir?

Comment: No estoy seguro de que versión usuaron, pero la dll que usaron es esta 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel2000.ApplicationClass' y le he intentado con office 2010 y 2016